# Always on top only for application

Tags: java, focus

I want my main frame on top of the other frames that are used in my application. I could use setAlwaysOnTop, but then it is also on top when I select another application.

Is there a way to have the frame on top of all the frames of my application, but not on windows of other applications?

-- Edit --

At the moment I just use setAlwaysOnTop. I was thinking about resetting it when the application looses focus and setting it back when it gets focus back. But at the moment I only see how to see focus change for a certain object. Is there a way to get notified about focus changes on the application level?

Answer (score 0):

maybe You can try use:

```
yourFrame.toFront();
yourFrame.repaint();
```

or just try to set order of components ?

Comment: I already tried that one, but that only brings the frame to the front: at the moment I click on another frame, that frame goes to the top.

I would like the frame to be on the top of all the frames of the application regardless of which frame is selected. But not on top of other applications when those are selected.

Answer (score 0):

@Cecil Westerhof from PDave's answer, What if you used a Thread to continuously order the frames? You could simply implement Runnable and have a run method drawing the frames in the right order. (I have never tried this so I have no idea if that would actually work.)